# Why does combining arrays and \left/\right cause alignment?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment

The following MWE is rendered as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  \left[\int abc\right]\\
  \left[abc\right]
\end{array}
\end{document}
```

[image: Misaligned brackets]

Why aren't the left brackets aligned? Removing the `\int` fixes it, but why? **Is there a way to fix the alignment?** (My real example involves nested arrays instead of an integral, but this was the simplest I could get).

Comment: Off-topic: Something bizarre seems to be happening: Your MWE doesn't switch to math mode to typeset the `array`. Nevertheless, the presence of the `[t]` position specifier seems to suffice to avoid generating an error message. If `[t]` is removed, it's necessary to place the `array` in math mode explicitly.

Comment: @Mico Interesting feature.

Comment: The brackets *are* aligned; it happens that the bigger one has a larger sidebearing on its left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  cause seems to be different size of brackets. For your (simple) case try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \left[\int abc\right]\\
  \left[\strut abc\right]
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Alternative solution is use `\bigl[ ...\bigr]` instead `left[ ...\right]`. With this you will achieve equal big brackets:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \bigl[\int abc\bigr]\\
  \bigl[ abc\bigr]
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how/why this work? (And ideally why I should have expected the behaviour above!)

Comment: Also, is there a way to add an "anti"`\strut` to the previous line instead?

Comment: Good questions ... Problem is probably that bracket in your MWE has different size, added `\strut`, which add invisible vertical lines before "abc", which make brackets around "abc" equal big as they are around `\int`. Of course, the given solution works just for given example. I will edit my answer.